# Use of `get` and `toSqlKey` in persistent

Tags: haskell, persistent, servant

I'm trying to use persistent-postgresql with servant.

I have a `User` model.

I want to have an endpoint that takes an id and returns the user with that id.

According to other answers I can use `toSqlKey` to turn an `Int64` into a `Key` to feed to `get`.

My function looks like:

```
oneUser :: Int64 -> App (Entity User)
oneUser userId = do
  maybeUser <- runDb $ get $ toSqlKey userId
  case maybeUser of
    Nothing ->
      throwError err404
    Just user ->
      return user
```

When I try to compile I get the error `Couldn't match expected type ‘PersistEntityBackend (Entity User)’ with actual type ‘SqlBackend’`

Use of `selectList` works fine.

```
allUsers :: App [Entity User]
allUsers = runDb $ selectList [] []
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and where I should look in the future for stuff like this. I couldn't find `get` on hackage/the right version of the library on stackage etc.

`runDb` looks like:

```
runDb :: (MonadReader Config m, MonadIO m) => SqlPersistT IO b -> m b
runDb query = do
  pool <- asks getPool
  liftIO $ runSqlPool query pool
```

taken from [this github project](https://github.com/parsonsmatt/servant-persistent/blob/master/src/Models.hs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `get ...` returns a plain `User` not an `Entity User`, so this will work:

```
altSingleUser :: Int64 -> App User
altSingleUser userid = do
    let foo = get (toSqlKey userid) :: SqlPersistT IO (Maybe User)
    maybeUser <- runDb $ foo
    case maybeUser of
         Nothing ->
            throwError err404
         Just person ->
            return person
```

If you want to return an `Entity User`, just change the last return statement to:

```
return $ Entity { entityKey = toSqlKey userid, entityVal = person }
```

Comment: What's the `let maybeUser = Nothing` doing in there? Is that a typo?

Comment: It's a leftover from experimentation :-)  I just tested it again, and It works without that line.

Comment: Thanks. The Entity data constructor is what I was looking for.