# How to resolve type mismatch between SqlBackend and PersistEntityBackend?

Tags: haskell, monads, servant

Using both the `servant` and `persistent` libraries to create a REST API and I'm running into a type mismatch error using `insertUnique` to create a new Entity.

Here's the offending function:

```
createUser :: Entity User -> App Int64
createUser p = do
    maybeNewUser <- runDb (insertUnique (User (userUsername $ entityVal p) (userSpotifyUser $ entityVal p)))
    case maybeNewUser of
        Nothing -> throwError err400
        Just newUser -> return $ fromSqlKey newUser
```

With the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘persistent-2.2.4.1:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.SqlBackend’
        with actual type ‘persistent-2.2.4.1:Database.Persist.Class.PersistEntity.PersistEntityBackend
                            (String
                             -> String
                             -> time-1.5.0.1:Data.Time.Clock.UTC.UTCTime
                             -> time-1.5.0.1:Data.Time.Clock.UTC.UTCTime
                             -> User)’
In the first argument of ‘runDb’, namely
[snip]
```

And for reference, the `runDb` function:

```
runDb :: (MonadReader Config m, MonadIO m) => SqlPersistT IO b -> m b
runDb query = do
    pool <- asks getPool
    liftIO $ runSqlPool query pool
```

And the `App` newtype:

```
newtype App a = App
    { runApp :: ReaderT Config (ExceptT ServantErr IO) a } deriving
        (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Config, MonadError ServantErr, MonadIO)
```

I've tried type hinting the result of `insertUnique` as `SqlBackend`, but that causes an equally confusing error. Are the `SqlBackend` and `PersistentEntityBackend` types not interchangeable?

Or perhaps the monad is malformed?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055829/use-of-get-and-tosqlkey-in-persistent).

Like `get` and others, `insertUnique` in this context returns a plain `User` not an `Entity User`.

```
createUser :: User -> App Int64
createUser p = do
    user <- (User (userUsername $ entityVal p) (userSpotifyUser $ entityVal p))
    let insertUser = insertUnique user :: SqlPersistT IO (Maybe (Key User))
    maybeNewUserKey <- runDb insertUser
    case maybeNewUserKey of
        Nothing -> throwError err400
        Just newUserKey ->
            return $ fromSqlKey newUserKey
```

Makes much more sense in hindsight since `runDb` accepts a `SqlPersistT` transformed monad.